# Uploading bigger files using PHP fails

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to upload a file with the size of e.g. `244 KB` via `POST` request with `PHP` but it causes a `403 Forbidden` error. When I upload a small file (e.g. `3 B`) it works fine.

I've made sure my `PHP.ini` is configured to support bigger files as seen below in the [`CPanel`](https://cpanel.net) screenshot:

[image]

My PHP script is the following:

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$fileData = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents($filename, $fileData);
```

Error handling and such removed for clarity.

Adding a `user agent` to the `POST` request does not help.

What could be the cause of bigger files being refused to be uploaded?

Comment: after saving the changes in your php.ini file have you restarted your server?cause if not you need to do that.

Comment: you can reload the config changes by `service apache reload`.

Comment: `CPanel` already reloaded the server after changing the config. This isn't the problem, the file size wasn't that low to begin with.

Comment: Do you have Apache mod_security Module Enabled? And Have you verified the Configuations are updated in your project with `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: @HarishST: The `phpinfo()` page says `PHP Version 7.4.6` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = Apache` but it does not mention `mod_security`

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076893/apache-403-forbidden-when-uploading-files